# What does it mean by 10/100Mbps in Lan card?

Tags: lan

10/100Mbps - It is written on specification of a internal Lan card.What does the 10 stands for ?ie - Data Rates -10/100Mbps for Half-Duplex mode,20/200Mbps for Full-Duplex mode.

Comment: No offence but I'm slightly surprised someone wouldn't know this [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer) with specific reference to the "Base T" varients would be VERY educational I suspect.

Answer (score 4):

It means the card supports both 10 Mbps (10BASE-T Ethernet) and 100 Mbps (100BASE-T "Fast Ethernet") modes and can thus be used with hubs, switches or routers that support either.

Nowadays, this is considered obsolete, as nearly all recently produced equipment has supported Gigabit Ethernet for years. But it typically still supports the older modes as well.

However, such an older card can cause problems for other users, since some cheaper switches will only support the older modes by switching completely to the lower speed, so that a single computer with a 100 Mbps LAN card can prevent everyone else from using Gigabit Ethernet.

Comment: I suspect the only place you'd find fast ethernet these days is on things like embedded devices, and homeplug AV adaptors. You'd also often have devices like routers have different coloured link-lights for these - often amber instead of green